# Is it possible to create partition with value containing '/' in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a dataset about docker images. You know the unique name of docker image is `<owner>/<image name>`, such as `library/nginx`, `jenkins/jenkins`.

I would like to use Athena to query the dataset with partition key `image-name`. But the value of `image-name` contains character `/`, is there any way to create partition key in Glue table with value containing `/`?

Comment: I researched this one for a bit and couldn't find you a definitive answer, even from the underlying Hive code; that being said, as the "/" character is used as the default separator all over Hadoop, Athena, EMR, et al., I would be shocked if this were in fact possible.  Have you tried /image-owner=jenkins/image-name=jenkins/<data> instead?   This would work, as an alternative

Comment: if these can be quoted you could win. I tested with something like this:

`"sample", "eman/name", "something", "today" ` and my partition column was col1 i.e "eman/name" in s3 the key was: " %22eman%2Fname%22"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It really helps.